# lidar not publishing /scan data

Tags: ros, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am currently working on robopeak rplidar,

I used github to setup everything,now everything is running good .but when i launched view_rplidar.launch it launched everything including RVIZ As expected ,but RVIZ didn't show lidar data in its GUI.

When i checked " rostopic echo /scan " it was not publishing anything .

I asked samething on support@robopeak.com they asked to check ros is having the access of rplidar or not
I checked that also by overwriting "sudo chmode a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0"

Yet problem is same .... Rplidar is not publishing/scan data
What can be the other problems

I have configured  tf also .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218255/lidar-not-publishing-/scan-data/) by [denim_patel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24047/denim_patel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Disconnect the sensor type in a terminal dmesg and memorise the last lines. Connect the sensor and enter the dmesg command, look for the memorised lines and some lines later you can see something like /dec/acm... Or /dev/ttyU...  the you need the permision for this device chmod or chown and you have to configure the device in the configs your prlaser node

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0